# bootstrap input-group 1px misallignment between addon and input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html - using Bootstrap

```
<div class="input-group" style="width:100px;">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-time" ></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

which produces the following very annoying output

[image]

A very annoying 1-2px aligning difference between input and addon - and I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is.
Can be seen in this [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/CLVPqDbPlk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ' .glyphicon ' has a top 1 px put it in 0, as `.glyphicon {top: 0px}`

Comment: I knew there was a reason for my move to fontawesome :) Thanks worked like a charm (thought i had already implemented it, but seems like i had it on a different selector

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar issue. The reason is I compiled bootstrap sass and Sass Number Precision parameter was set to 5. It must be >= 8 to avoid the issue. Hope it will help if someone is compiling Bootstrap with Sass.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this behaviour is the glyphicon class.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

I put a second span into the first one and it looks nice.